# Casting array to string in Java and python implementation

Tags: java, arrays, string, casting

There is this following code that I am having a problem wrapping my head around what `(String)` does. I am assuming that it is taking IR which is attached to a java panel(setvalue), casts memoryArray into a string, and sets the value of IR as that string but I am not sure. If yes, how does this differ from doing toString() as it is also used to cast array to string.

Also, I was wondering if this is possible to do in python simply.

```
 public static final int IR = 1;   
 int address2 = 3;
          
 Object[][] memoryArray = new Object[256][17];
 int memR2 = address2/16;
 int memC2 = address2 % 16 + 1;
 IR.setValue((" "+(String) memoryArray[memoryRow][memoryCol]).trim()); 
 System.out.println(IR);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casting `(String) memoryArray[memoryRow][memoryCol]` would work *only* if the array contains a `String` object at `[memoryRow][memoryCol]`, otherwise a runtime `ClassCastException` is thrown.

It is not the same as calling `toString()` method of `Object` which *converts* the object of any class to `String`.  If object at `[memoryRow][memoryCol]` happens to be `null`, call to the `toString` method will result in `NullPointerException`.